# Error When trying to use Solana-SDK

Tags: solana-sdk

I am getting this error `this struct takes 0 lifetime arguments but 1 lifetime argument was supplied` when trying to use the `solana-sdk = { version = "1.16.9" }` crate.

For my CLI environment, I am using version `1.16.9`

Below are the full logs

```
Error: Function _ZN209_$LT$curve25519_dalek..window..NafLookupTable8$LT$curve25519_dalek..backend..serial..curve_models..ProjectiveNielsPoint$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..convert..From$LT$$RF$curve25519_dalek..edwards..EdwardsPoint$GT$$GT$4from17h1c13beefdabbe951E Stack offset of 11000 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 6904 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
Error: Function _ZN205_$LT$curve25519_dalek..window..NafLookupTable8$LT$curve25519_dalek..backend..serial..curve_models..AffineNielsPoint$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..convert..From$LT$$RF$curve25519_dalek..edwards..EdwardsPoint$GT$$GT$4from17hb3939ff33104a56cE Stack offset of 8352 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 4256 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
Error: Function _ZN116_$LT$curve25519_dalek..edwards..EdwardsBasepointTableRadix16$u20$as$u20$curve25519_dalek..traits..BasepointTable$GT$6create17h4999f75273e46a70E Stack offset of 30896 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 26800 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
Error: Function _ZN116_$LT$curve25519_dalek..edwards..EdwardsBasepointTableRadix32$u20$as$u20$curve25519_dalek..traits..BasepointTable$GT$6create17h5eae7f13544a0a72E Stack offset of 62896 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 58800 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
Error: Function _ZN116_$LT$curve25519_dalek..edwards..EdwardsBasepointTableRadix64$u20$as$u20$curve25519_dalek..traits..BasepointTable$GT$6create17h55f24b3221f81e35E Stack offset of 113944 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 109848 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
Error: Function _ZN117_$LT$curve25519_dalek..edwards..EdwardsBasepointTableRadix128$u20$as$u20$curve25519_dalek..traits..BasepointTable$GT$6create17he4aaab1650e2dde2E Stack offset of 227864 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 223768 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
Error: Function _ZN117_$LT$curve25519_dalek..edwards..EdwardsBasepointTableRadix256$u20$as$u20$curve25519_dalek..traits..BasepointTable$GT$6create17he5f6f153e4c2c787E Stack offset of 506896 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 502800 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
Error: Function _ZN212_$LT$curve25519_dalek..window..LookupTableRadix64$LT$curve25519_dalek..backend..serial..curve_models..ProjectiveNielsPoint$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..convert..From$LT$$RF$curve25519_dalek..edwards..EdwardsPoint$GT$$GT$4from17he042683c35faf1a9E Stack offset of 5648 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 1552 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
Error: Function _ZN208_$LT$curve25519_dalek..window..LookupTableRadix64$LT$curve25519_dalek..backend..serial..curve_models..AffineNielsPoint$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..convert..From$LT$$RF$curve25519_dalek..edwards..EdwardsPoint$GT$$GT$4from17hc75e92a98b7ef494E Stack offset of 4360 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 264 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
Error: Function _ZN213_$LT$curve25519_dalek..window..LookupTableRadix128$LT$curve25519_dalek..backend..serial..curve_models..ProjectiveNielsPoint$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..convert..From$LT$$RF$curve25519_dalek..edwards..EdwardsPoint$GT$$GT$4from17h8141b40b221d8f47E Stack offset of 10768 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 6672 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
Error: Function _ZN209_$LT$curve25519_dalek..window..LookupTableRadix128$LT$curve25519_dalek..backend..serial..curve_models..AffineNielsPoint$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..convert..From$LT$$RF$curve25519_dalek..edwards..EdwardsPoint$GT$$GT$4from17h73ea8ff8b5f63411E Stack offset of 8200 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 4104 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
Error: Function _ZN213_$LT$curve25519_dalek..window..LookupTableRadix256$LT$curve25519_dalek..backend..serial..curve_models..ProjectiveNielsPoint$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..convert..From$LT$$RF$curve25519_dalek..edwards..EdwardsPoint$GT$$GT$4from17hb1cb5bdd4558d796E Stack offset of 21008 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 16912 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
Error: Function _ZN209_$LT$curve25519_dalek..window..LookupTableRadix256$LT$curve25519_dalek..backend..serial..curve_models..AffineNielsPoint$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..convert..From$LT$$RF$curve25519_dalek..edwards..EdwardsPoint$GT$$GT$4from17h14d024fb35937fe6E Stack offset of 15880 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 11784 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
   Compiling termcolor v1.2.0
   Compiling atty v0.2.14
   Compiling serde_with v2.3.3
   Compiling anchor-derive-space v0.28.0
error[E0425]: cannot find function `is` in this scope
  --> src/lib.rs:98:6
   |
98 |     !is(stream)
   |      ^^ not found in this scope

error[E0107]: this struct takes 0 lifetime arguments but 1 lifetime argument was supplied
   --> src/lib.rs:418:20
    |
418 |     StdoutLock(io::StdoutLock<'a>),
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^---- help: remove these generics
    |                    |
    |                    expected 0 lifetime arguments

error[E0107]: this struct takes 0 lifetime arguments but 1 lifetime argument was supplied
   --> src/lib.rs:419:20
    |
419 |     StderrLock(io::StderrLock<'a>),
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^---- help: remove these generics
    |                    |
    |                    expected 0 lifetime arguments

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0425`.
For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0107`.
error: could not compile `termcolor` due to 2 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: could not compile `atty` due to previous error
```

Answer (score 3):

You're probably trying to use `solana-sdk` in an on-chain program. `solana-sdk` contains many things that are not available to on-chain programs, such as randomness, private keys, etc.

You must use the `solana-program` crate in your on-chain program and remove `solana-sdk`. You can use it in tests as a `dev-dependency` though

Comment: I want to sign a TX on the on-chain program and send it. 

Is this possible with the `solana-sdk`?

Comment: That's not possible to do at all. While on-chain, you can do a cross-program invocation into another program, however, where you send one instruction to another program. Note that you can only invoke programs that were passed to your program. https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/calling-between-programs#cross-program-invocations for more info